# VBA EXcel - Subtracting active sheet cell from prior day sheet cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet that I track the daily inventory by account and make sure I balance to the G/L. I have a VBA set up that creates my new sheet and names it as per current date. At the bottom of the sheet I have formulas that give me the change in inventory value from today minus yesterday. Since that formula isn't something I need to "update" daily I am looking to write the formula in the VBA.

I am getting myself caught up on how to write the VBA for the change in sheet name when the new sheet is created.

For example, I have a sheet named "05.10.16" that has a formula that takes `B8 - '05.09.16'!B8` and shows the result. So I open the spreadsheet today and create today's sheet, "05.11.16".

What is the coding I need in VBA to update that formula `ActiveCell.Formula = "B8 - ws2.cell(B8)"`?

I have `set ws1 = ActiveSheet`, but having trouble defining `ws2`. `ws2` will be a moving target once the new sheet is added for the day.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? You should accept the answer that best solves your problem. That a valuable signal to other who stumble accross your question later on. Also, accepting an answer provides reputation to the answerer, and you get a small amount as well!

Answer (score 0):

If you add a sheet with VBA you get a reference to that worksheet in return. Just save it to a variable and you can access it later on:

```
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add("05.11.16")
```

You can use the workbook's `Address` property (possibly with the fourth parameter set to True) to retrieve the address that you have to change your formula to.